# R ~ dplyr::case_when %in% 35:39, only selects integers such as 35.0 but not values with fractions e.g. 35.1

Tags: r, dplyr, integer, operators, case-when

## Background

I am trying to subset participants based on various blood-levels and other factors such as age, and then score these results.

The **#1 problem** is that %in% -operator only subsets the values that are integers (e.g. ages 35.0 or 38.0) but not the rational numbers with 1/10 fractions other than .0 such as 48.6 or 56.7.

The **#2 problem** also applies to %in% and fractions. In this case, %in% with a range of e.g. 1.29:1.55 only picks up values that are exactly 1.29 or 1.55 but nothing in-between.

Should I somehow specify to R that I am subsetting values by their 1/10 fractions? The range works perfectly fine when the values are integers such as %in% 200:205 would subset values of 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205. Yet for some reason, if I wanted to choose a range %in% 20.0:20.5, it gives me 20.0 and 20.5, not 20.0, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4 and 20.5.

```
File.Score <- File %>%
  filter(sex == "FEMALE") %>%
  mutate(Score.Age = case_when(age_sc %in% 35:39 ~ 2,
                           age_sc %in% 40:44 ~ 4,
                           age_sc %in% 45:49 ~ 5,
                           TRUE ~ 0))

File.Score <- File %>%
  filter(sex == "FEMALE") %>%
  mutate(Score.HDL = case_when(HDL > 1.55 ~ -2,
                           HDL %in% 1.29:1.55 ~ -1,
                           HDL %in% 1.16:1.29 ~ 0,
                           HDL %in% 0.9:1.16 ~ 1,
                           HDL < 0.9 ~ 2))

ISSUE 1
#Range of ages that should be scored
head(File$Age, 50)
 [1] 42.3 26.3 29.2 59.8 36.1 43.0 56.7 48.6 47.0 42.2 38.0

#Ages that are scored 
head(File.Score$Score.Age, 11)
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA 4 NA NA 5 NA 2

#In other words, only the integers are chosen with a 1/10 fraction of 0.

ISSUE 2
#Range of HDL-values that should be scored
head(File$HDL, 11)
 [1] 1.67 1.73 2.05 0.95 1.38 1.60 1.51 1.29 1.34 1.27 1.18

#HDL-values scored
head(File.Score$Score.HDL, 11)

 [1] -2 -2 -2 NA NA NA NA -1 NA NA NA

#Only the values that are specified by > -operator and those at the edges 
of the range are subset. Values between 1.29 and 1.55 are not subset.
```

The same problem occurred when I tried with *ifelse* instead of *case_when*.

I should probably add some specifications to the code but I cannot figure out what it could be.

- I use Rstudio version 1.1.447
- I use dplyr version 0.8.0.1
- All the values are numeric as.doubles, and not as.integers.

Comment: Yes, that's how the `base` function `%in%` works. Perhaps you are looking for `%between%`, as in `%between% c(35, 38)`

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply Gregor! For some reason, the `age_sc %between% c(35, 38)` did not work but when I used `case_when(between(age_sc, 35, 39)~2)` it worked!! -Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Ah, I got mixed up. `data.table` defines `%between%` as an infix operator. `dplyr` just has `between()` as you have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Gregor!

The `between` turned out to be the solution to the problem.

```
File.Score <- File %>%
  filter(sex == "FEMALE") %>%
  mutate(Score.Age = case_when(between(age_sc, 35, 39) ~ 2,
                           between(age_sc, 40, 44) ~ 4,
                           between(age_sc, 45, 49) ~ 5,
                           TRUE ~ 0))
```